# Can a flex web app access a sqlite database?

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, database-connection

I'm making an application (web based) using flex and i have a requirment to access the SQLite database on the local system. There is **no** server running and i've decided to give them the link to the html file and see how that works out.

So in the root directory, there will be all required swf, html files, etc and a .db file. Can i access that database thro the flex *web application* ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Flex can access an SQLite database via the Air SDK, but you are out of luck when running from the browser sandbox/SDK.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like to use AIR SDK, You can do that by Java applet. You can make a collection of needed JavaScript functions on the web page to be called by Flex and their will call a Java applets functions to deal with SQLite instead of using HTTP services.